# Performance Testing Career

Tags: automated-testing, load-testing, jmeter, qtp

I've been recently reading a lot about performance testing and I really like it. My plan is to move my career into that specialty.

My questions are:

- What are the best tools in demand right now?
- How is the future in performance testing? Good or bad, and why?
- Is performance testing critical and important for companies?

Answer (score 1):

Good luck in your intention.

The most popular proprietary/paid performance testing tools as for now are:

- [HP LoadRunner](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/loadrunner-load-testing/)
- [Borland Silk Performer](http://www.borland.com/Products/Software-Testing/Performance-Testing/Silk-Performer)
- [Microsoft Visual Studio Load Testing Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293540%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Each tool has free trial so you should be able to perform your own assessment, Loadrunner seems to be the most popular one.

In regards to free/open source tools, currently the choices are in

- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [Gatling](http://gatling.io/)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

As aforementioned tools are free there is no problem to download and try out each one. However if your time is limited you can refer to [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](http://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) guide.

Performance testing domain is very actual as it evidenced by Apple’s iPhone 6 Web Failure, outages of e-commerce sites on i.e. Black Friday, Xmas, NY, etc. when thousands of dollars is lost for each minute due to servers overload. Besides, due to work complexity, need to have experience in different domains apart from performance testing tool itself (application servers, databases, networking, etc.) makes performance testers more highly paid comparing to i.e. test automation engineers or manual testers.

Comment: Thank you. Does the performance engineer also fix the bottlenecks and slow-response time? If yes, how do you fix them, generally speaking?

Comment: Usually performance test engineer doesn't fix bottlenecks but he tries to provide as much information as possible to help the developer to localize the problem i.e. profiler snapshots, memory dumps and maps, logs, server side health status, etc.

Comment: @DmitriT What other things a performance tester needs to know apart from testing tool like Jmeter?

Comment: @PriyanshuShekhar Planning the test and reporting defects. Databases and hardware knowledge is also important. Because you have to analyze jMeter results.

Comment: @DmitriT Do you work with performance testing?

Comment: I would like to add FunkLoad to the open source list: http://funkload.nuxeo.org/